# How to decrease the image width and height depend upon phone using constraints?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I am like to know is there any possibility to increase and decrease the width and height of UI objects.

[image]

1.Took this image as example ,This is collection view designed for iphone 6.

2.while build the project image occupy two in a row.

3.while i run this for iphone5,iphone4s only one image can occupy the row.

4.so i like to know is there any way to achieve image should place for each phone should have two image inside the collection cell.

5.**I have tried to set constraint for collection cell but later i understood no possible**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the size of item in code using:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:
```

and

```
- (CGFloat)collectionView:layout:minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:
```

Make sure you calculate the real width of each cell based on the screen width: `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width`

Comment: Either use constraints OR calculate yourself. Mixing will give you tons of funny defects

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Constraint Problem there ,

Give Top, Bottom , Leading , Trailing constraint to image view

**DO NOT** Fix Height Width

Hope it works for  you

Comment: i didn't set constraints for image.. And there is no option to set constraints for collection cell that is problem @prashanth

Comment: @KishoreKumar what you exactly want to do

Comment: i want to show two images in one row is there any possible @Prashanth

Comment: Ok i think you want cell spacing and Line Spacing between cell for View